# next sheet reference within a formula for a macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in Excel that generates / inserts a formula in the active cell of the current sheet.

Generically, the formula should simply be

= A - B,

whereby:

'A' is cell D66 of the next sheet (in a series of sheets), and

'B' is cell D67 of the next sheet after the next sheet (so two sheets to the right of the active sheet)

Note that I want the macro to generate the [= A - B ] formula in the active cell and not merely the numerical result of A - B.

Also, the names of the 'next' and 'next-next' tabs change daily, which is why I need to reference them according to their position relative to the active sheet instead of  a hard coded name.  The actual cell reference (D66 and D67) in the respective tabs does not change however.

Many thanks for any help you can give on this

Comment: I can give you the code for this but first i would like to know your thoughts on this. How do you think the logic would work? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Before you create that formula, you need to take into account few things

`1` What happens when we have 4 sheets say Sheet1, Sheet2(Hidden), Sheet3 and sheet4. Do you want the formula to pick up values from Sheet2 and sheet3 or Sheet3 and sheet4?
`2` You have more than 2 sheet after the sheet where you want to put the formula

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Very simple:</strike>

```
Sub FormulaMaker()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, namee As String
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Next
    namee = sh.Name & "!"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & namee & "D66-" & namee & "D67"
End Sub
```

**Note:**

This will fail if the active sheet is the last sheet.

**Edit#1:**

Here is the correction as per   Siddharth Rout's comments:

```
Sub FormulaMaker()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, namee As String
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, namee2 As String
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Next
    Set sh2 = sh.Next
    namee = sh.Name & "!"
    namee2 = sh2.Name & "!"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & namee & "D66-" & namee2 & "D67"
End Sub
```

This simple approach will not work if the successor sheets are hidden

Comment: It is not that simple :)  It will also fail when the sheets are invisible in between two sheets...

Comment: Also there are 3 sheets involved and not 2 ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout  Thank you!........I have tried to address one of the two issues in my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: + 1 for incorporating the changes :) However, If you are planning to give the code in a platter, then I suggest you might as well do the complete job :D

Comment: Thanks very much both of you.  the corrected version works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Thank you both very much.  The amended solution works and is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated..